# How to get production dev token for evernote

Tags: api, evernote

For a couple of month the generation of developer tokens for evernote production is disabled: https://www.evernote.com/api/DeveloperToken.action
How can i obtain a dev token for prod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an issue with creating dev token, you should go to https://www.evernote.com/SupportLogin.action and reach out to the support team. They can get you connected with a new developer token.