# Evernote API approved but can't create developer token for production server

Tags: api, sandbox, production, evernote

Okay so After working on sandbox of Evernote, I applied for production server API approval few days ago. So recently i got mail from their customer support stating that they have activated my API key on production server. So i can't figure out what to do next,i tried creating dev token for production server but it says that currently creation of developer token is disabled.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ifrx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dev token and API keys for OAuth are two different things. If you just want to create a dev token for your account, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47041244/1691992).